# OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted in ansible

Tags: ansible

From my CentOS(Ansible controller host) trying to run below playbook.

**Ansible version:-**

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.21
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

```yaml
    ---
    - hosts: pro-server
      become: yes
      remote_user: root
      tasks:
        - name: Set authorized key taken from file
          ansible.posix.authorized_key:
            user: root
            state: present
            key: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

It fails with below error.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts add-ssh-key.yml

PLAY [pro-server] ****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [50.51.52.24]

TASK [Set authorized key taken from file] ********************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
fatal: [50.51.52.24]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to make /tmp/tmp73HusP into to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, failed final rename from /root/.ssh/.ansible_tmpy4MPxlauthorized_keys: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
50.51.52.24             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

added the following to **/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg**. However still same problem persists.

```
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
```

Any pointer to solve this problem will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled on the target machine?

Comment: No. it is disabled. `SELinux status: disabled`

Comment: What are the actual perms of your authorized_keys file ? You should also run `lsattr authorized_keys` and make sure the file has not been made immutable (i.e. with the `i` attribute). Modify accordingly with `chattr -i authorized_keys` if relevant.

Comment: On target host it is having `lsattr ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-----a--------e--- /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: There you got your problem. `man chattr`: "A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be open in append mode for writing.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute."

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator and toydarian for the pointer, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is an `'a'` attribute set on the `authorized_keys` file.
From `man chattr`:

> A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be open in append mode for writing.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

This can be fixed using the [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html):

```yaml
- name: make sure the 'a' attribute is removed from the authorized_keys-file
  file:
    path: '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys'
    attributes: '-a'
```